# How to treat plus sign from user input as part of input string and not as concat operator?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

This is for a small internal tool to enable a few people to query the database. The query has a plus sign as below:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(DateName(month,CreatedOn),0,4) + ' - ' + SUBSTRING(CAST(Year(CreatedOn) AS varchar(10)),3,3) as Month, Year(CreatedOn) as Year,
```

The query is passed to the server using a jquery ajax call

```
 var d = "query=" + $("#txtQuery").val();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '/Reports/GetReport',
                data: d,
```

However, I get a server error and debugging I find that the query on the server is missing the plus sign. i.e.

```
 SELECT SUBSTRING(DateName(month,CreatedOn),0,4)  ' - '  SUBSTRING(CAST(Year(CreatedOn) AS varchar(10)),3,3) as Month
```

And from FireBug,

```
localhost:1489/Reports/GetReport?query=SELECT%20SUBSTRING(DateName(month,CreatedOn),0,4)%20+%20%27%20-%20%27%20+%20SUBSTRING(CAST(Year(CreatedOn)%20AS%20varchar(10)),3,3)%20as%20Month,%20Year(CreatedOn)%20as%20Year..
```

How do I ensure that the plus is treated as a part of the input string and not as a concat operator which seems to be the case here.

Comment: `SELECT 'You let your users enter SQL to run?'; DROP TABLE Students;`

Comment: @nnnnnn Heck with that: `DROP TABLE Students` works here. Although doesn't provide a built-in way to make that comment :P

Comment: @nnnnnn There are checks on the server which will prevent that query from executing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"+" is treated as a space in URIs.

Use [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent).

Comment: "+" is a reserved character as mentioned in the link you provided. So encodeURI won't really solve the issue. But is there any other way around it?

Answer (score 1):

Or you just avoid the +

```
SELECT CONAT(SUBSTRING(DateName(month,CreatedOn),0,4), ' - ', SUBSTRING(CAST(Year(CreatedOn) AS varchar(10)),3,3)) as Month, Year(CreatedOn) as Year,..
```

Answer (score 0):

The + isn't escaped when it is transmitted via HTTP, so you'll need to escape it manually on the client and then unescape it on the server before using it.

Comment: Actually, in this case if he *unescaped* what came in to the server, he would get bad data. It's only the `+` sign that is not being escaped properly, and the server is unescaping properly, it seems.

Comment: ah yes... well... the important thing is that the + is the issue, not some other problem :)